# How do I pass a cell value to Range to use as its address?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that requires the user to enter a range of cells.  I do this with an input box

```
Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=8)
Range("C3").Value = Range1.Address(External:=True)
```

I want the user to be able to run the script again, but just reuse the previous range.  I'm saving the address to a cell, and am now trying to pass that info from the cell BACK to the range...  Its giving me a type mismatch.  Below is how I am (probably too simply) trying to pass the information back.

```
Set Range1.Address = Cells(3, 3).Value
```

However, if I copy the previous range and paste that into the dialog box, it works fine.  I believe I'm just not passing the data right.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Address` property is read-only. It can't be used to change the range. Instead, just use the `Range` function:

```
Set Range1 = Range(Cells(3,3).Value)
```

should work.